# How to find the number of common elements between 1D array vs 3D array?

Tags: arrays, performance, arraylist, collections, mql5

I want to find the number of common elements of arr1 (1D) inside arr2 (3D), not using loops.

arr1=[1,2,3];

arr2=[y][x][1,2,3,4,5,6];

(y and x could be any index).

Output: 3.

The thing is to be able to run on MQL5, by importing numPy or similar.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
             [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
             [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])
flatarray = arr2.flatten()
common_elements = np.intersect1d(arr1, flatarray)
a = len(common_elements)
print(a)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Is there a way to flat an array with specific index of the first two dimensions in the same 3D array. ([y][x][all elements])? Thats the only thing I have not solved yet.

Comment: Yes here it is                                                                                                  
index_to_flatten = 1
flat_array = arr3.reshape(arr3.shape[0], -1)[index_to_flatten]

Answer (score 0):

```
 **try this**   

func countCommonElements(_ array1D: [Int], _ array3D: [[[Int]]]) -> Int {
    let flattenedArray3D = array3D.flatMap { $0.flatMap { $0 } }

    var count = 0

    for element in array1D {
        if flattenedArray3D.contains(element) {
            count += 1
        }
    }

    return count
}

// Example
let array1D = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let array3D = [[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[1, 2], [9, 10]]]

let commonElementsCount = countCommonElements(array1D, array3D)
print(commonElementsCount) // Output: 2
```

Comment: Makes sense Sahil. Now the question is how to make the same, but counting just the common elements of the specific index [y][x][]. As your example, how to know if there is a common element just in arr2 [0][0][5,6] and not the total common elements of the whole 3D array. I will appreciate it!
array1D = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array3D = [[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[1, 2], [9, 10]]].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).